# What is the difference between import and extends in java?

Tags: java

How is extends differ from import ? And if a class, say class CLASS1, imports a package then does the class CLASS2, which has created an object of class one, needs to import the same package for using its methods?

```
import javax.swing.Jframe;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class textbox extends JFrame{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Importing tells the compiler where to find the class to get its definition, variables, methods, etc...without needing to qualify the full name in the current class you are writing.
>
> Extending a class makes the child class inherit the variables/methods/etc... In other words, you have access to all of the fields and methods of the extended class.

According to [link](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-theory-questions/12762-difference-between-extending-importing-class.html)

Comment: Looks like this was based on http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-theory-questions/12762-difference-between-extending-importing-class.html :) Or maybe it's just such a common explanation that it's the same everywhere.